# How do I use dct to extract features from image?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I want to process large images set and encountered memory error. Can we **extracted features** and process them using **DCT** or an other algorithm?

Comment: Can you please post the memory error or exception which you are getting in your program currently?

Comment: Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.